# FB.api dont get email

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im starting usi FB.api to make access to my website with facebook account.

I use, by example this code, token directly from facebook developers:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '00000000',
            xfbml      : true,
            cookie     : true,
            version    : 'v2.5'
        }); 

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
  };

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into your Facebook.';
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=last_name,gender,first_name,email', function(response) {
      console.log('Accesso effettuato: ' + response.first_name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Grazie per essere entrata, ' + response.last_name + response.email +
        "<img src='" + "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture?type=large' alt='' />";
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });

  }
```

The problem is that no fields email is showen! Where is the problem?!
I also check my facebook account to make email visible for other apps/web but nothing change!
Is it a wrong code?!

Comment: where is your login code?

Comment: <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>

Comment: is the email address confirmed?

Comment: yes, i check with my own profile... in console I see only: {"last_name":"Lorusso","gender":"male","first_name":"Mario","id":"11111111111"}

Comment: did you try it in the api explorer?

Comment: Also with fb api explorer (setting the token to email) the result calling me?fields=id,name,email is: {"id": "1047542218630287","name": "Mario Lorusso"}

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t even get an email in the API explorer after authorizing with the email permissions, there are only 2 options why it does not work:

- Your email is not confirmed
- You are using a phone number for your Facebook login

Check your User Settings.